# Update Script from Select

Tags: sql-server-2008

I need your support here.I want to change this to an update statement,I want to update all null values of E.Age with Birthage from PersonDeatl .The below script just selects .Table Employee and and PersonDeatl do not have keys to join them nor with EmpRet.Thanks guys

```
select distinct * from ((Select     
           E.EmployeeId,E.Address,E.City,E.Zip,E.State,E.Age
         from Employee E join
          EmpRet R
            on E.EmployeeId=R.EmployeeId
        where R.Dscription='Age not Qualify'  and E.Age is null)Ag inner join
       (select address,city,zip,state,BirthAge from PersonDeatl)Pd

          on ag.Address=Pd.Address and ag.City=Pd.City and ag.zip=Pd.Zip)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this.

```
With  EmpCTE ( Age, BirthAge ) as (
   SELECT E.Age, P.BirthAge
   FROM Employee  E  
   JOIN PersonDeatl P
   ON E.Address = P.Address
   AND E.City=P.City 
   AND E.Zip=P.Zip
   Where E.Age IS NULL
)

UPDATE EmpCTE 
SET Age = BirthAge
```